# Проблема запуска Excel файлов с помощью Process.Start() на C#

Tags: c#, excel

Здравствуйте!
Пишу программу, которая по расписанию запускает Excel файлы(в них есть макрос, который обращается к базе и составляет отчет), для каждого файла есть время выполнения. Если файл за это время не выполнится(не завершится) или зависнет, то файл должен быть закрыт. Все это должно работать в Windows Service(пока тестирую как простую программу).

Выполнение каждого файла запускаю в отдельном потоке:

```
Task task = (Task)t;
        try
        {
            //sometimes start do not work corectly
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = @task.FilePath;
            try { proc.Start(); }
            catch { Logger.Log.Error("LounchProgramThread: cant start the program"); }

            DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime finish = current.AddMinutes(task.TimeExecuteFile);

            try
            {
                // wait until task will finish or time will pass
                // System.InvalidOperationException
                while ((!proc.HasExited) && (current.CompareTo(finish) < 0))
                {
                    current = DateTime.Now;
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }


                if (!proc.HasExited)
                { //if task do not finish 
                    Logger.Log.Debug("LaunchProgramThread: --Method-launchProgram: program do not finish. Task: " + task.ToString());
                    proc.Kill();
                    proc.WaitForExit();
                    Logger.Log.Error("LaunchProgramThread: --Method-launchProgram: program killed. Task: " + task.ToString());
                }
                else
                { //if task finished
                    Logger.Log.Info("LaunchProgramThread: process finished. " + task.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.Log.Error("LaunchProgramThread: proc is null. " + task.ToString() + e.StackTrace);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Log.Error("LounchProgramThread: cant launch the program. " + task.ToString() + "\n" +
            e.Message + e.StackTrace);
        }
```

Проблема в том, что если какой-то файл уже открыт(процесс Excel уже существует) то метод proc.Start(), запускает нужный скрипт но для уже запущенного процесса Excel(то есть присоединяет workbook), а иногда как нужно отдельным процессом, логику этого открытия я не нашел. Пробовал выносить Start() в отдельный метод и блокировать, разные варианты компоновки, но результата так и не достиг.

Можете что-то посоветовать?

**UPD**

Спасибо всем. Переделал все на Excel api, и открытие Workbook.
Вариант, сделать все на c# хороший, но эти скрипты писал не я (их много) и переписывать их не рационально, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это внутренняя логика Windows Shell'а.

Когда вы запускаете Excel'евский документ на «выполнение», Shell (точнее, функция `ShellExecuteEx`) проверяет, есть ли уже копия приложения в памяти. Если такая копия находится, shell копия просто отправляет первой копии имя файла, который вы хотите открыть. При этом вызов `Process.Start` возвращает `false` (а в обычном случае — `true`).

Вы должны воспользоваться этой информацией и просто знать, что возврат `false` из `Process.Start` означает, что документ был отправлен уже открытому процессу.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения, помогло понять структуру, и где порыться в исходниках! Пытался сделать еще, нормально не получалось. Вариант
StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"; StartInfo.Arguments = @task.FilePath; работает получше, но всё равно иногда запускало в одном процессе.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем так извращаться?

Вы можете проделать всю работу на стороне C# не прибегая к Excel.

Для этого вам понадобится либа EPPlus.

С помощью нее открываете/создаете новый файл, затем в коде C# обращаетесь к базе и заполняете, сохраняете.

Вот и все! И не нужно морочиться с процессами Excel.